# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND braintreePaypal.js

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova

I am using ionic angular to build Andriod/IOS app.

ionic version: 6.17.0
angular version: 11.2.14
gradle version: 6.9.1
cordova version:10.0.0

but I am facing this wall all the time I am trying to build it, the build is successful but when I try to build the Gradle
Capture
and run it in the android emulator this issue raises in the console:
//
braintreeClient.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
braintreePaypal.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
braintree.min.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
braintreeHostedFields.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
instamojo.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
animate.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles.css:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
runtime-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
cordova.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main-es2015.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
2css2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/assets/icon/favicon.png:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
css2:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
//
when hovering on the error below URL that appears:

file:///assets/others/braintreeClient.js

this file is there in the assets folder and its extinction is .js

if I could find any advice I will be thankful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have  these errors after building my app with cordova , after build app shows blank page , when inspect it this error was there